# Distance between two partitions with two elements in {1,...,m} satisfies triangle inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

For $z, z' \in \{ -1,1 \}^m$, define $d(z,z') = \min_{\delta \in \{ -1,1\}}\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{1}_{z_i \neq \delta z'_i}$. This is kind of like a distance between two partitions of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ of cardinal $2$.

Does $d$ satisfy the triangular inequality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more thinking I found that the answer is **yes** by writing $d(z,z') = \min_{\delta \in \{ -1,1\}}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m |z_i - \delta z'_i|$ and then consider all the $8$ possible values the three $\delta$ appearing in the inequality can take, which we can name from left to right $ \delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3$, and use the regular triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, if $(\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3) = (1,1,-1)$, then :

$d(a,c) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i - c_i| \leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i+c_i| = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i - b_i + b_i + c_i| \leq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i - b_i| + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m|b_i + c_i| = d(a,b) + d(b,c)$

I wonder if there is another proof though.